# How to iterate lines from a text file in python?

Tags: python, c, uart

I update my question because At first I think that I have the best solution However, I don't have it until now.It was my mistake in execution. I think that the error comes from the loop while in the file C.

I am trying to read lines from a text file"Plaintext.txt".

```
e0370734313198a2885a308d3243f6a8
ccddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233
8e73b0f7da0e6452c810f32bc4567a22
```

It contains now tow lines, I put just two in order to make simple test, but I must put more then 1000 texts (means more than 1000 lines)  I want to read each line then send it to the uart where I will do encryption for every plaintext (The encryption algorithm is in C): This is my script:

I edit it as you tell me but I still have the encryption of one line

```
    import string
import serial
import time
from array import array
import struct
import binascii

ser = serial.Serial(
                    port='COM4',\
                    baudrate=230400,\
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
                    timeout=0)  

f = open(r'C:\\Users\\user\\Plaintxt.txt', 'r')
for a in f:
   plaintxt_16b=a[0:32]
   plaintext=binascii.unhexlify(plaintxt_16b)
   clear_msg=b'\x24'+b'\x73'+b'\x10'+plaintext

ser.write(clear_msg)
time.sleep(0.4)

while True: 
  print(ser.read(70))
ser.close()                # close ports
```

In the C file:

```
   while(1)
    {
        int rx_length = dev_uart_ptr->uart_read((void*)rx_buffer, 19);

        if (rx_length <19)
        {

            if (rx_buffer[0]=='\x24')
            {
                if (rx_buffer[1]=='\x73')
                {
                    if (rx_buffer[2]=='\x10')
                    {
                        plaintext[0] = (rx_buffer[3] << 24)  |
                                (rx_buffer[4] << 16)  |
                                (rx_buffer[5] << 8)   |
                                rx_buffer[6];
                        plaintext[1] = (rx_buffer[7] << 24)  |
                                (rx_buffer[8] << 16)  |
                                (rx_buffer[9] << 8)   |
                                rx_buffer[10];
                        plaintext[2] = (rx_buffer[11] << 24) |
                                (rx_buffer[12] << 16) |
                                (rx_buffer[13] << 8)  |
                                rx_buffer[14];
                        plaintext[3] = (rx_buffer[15] << 24) |
                                (rx_buffer[16] << 16) |
                                (rx_buffer[17] << 8)  |
                                rx_buffer[18];

                        xprintf("**************************\n");
                        xprintf("%8x %8x %8x %8x \n",plaintext[0],plaintext[1],plaintext[2],plaintext[3]);
                        aes2_set_msg((unsigned int *)plaintext);    /** Reset AES message buffer */
                        aes2_set_key128((unsigned int *)key128);    /** Put the key 128 into AES */
                        /** Configure  AES register  to enable IRQ and ENCODE */
                        regs_aes2_ptr-> CFG =  AES2_CFG_ENC_DEC_BIT | AES2_CFG_IRQ_MASK_BIT;
                        /** Reset AES internaly */
                        regs_aes2_ptr-> CTRL = AES2_CTRL_SWRESET_BIT;

#if DEBUG
                        xprintf("Go encrypt..\n");
#endif
                        /** Start the ENCODE function */
                        regs_aes2_ptr-> CTRL = AES2_CTRL_START_BIT;

                        while(!aes2_irq_flag); /** Wait for irq flag */
                        aes2_irq_flag=0;    /** Reset irq flag */

#if DEBUG
                        xprintf("Encrypt done..\n");
#endif

                        aes2_get_msg((unsigned int *)ciphertext);   /** Retrieve encrypted message */
                        xprintf("%8x %8x %8x %8x \n",ciphertext[0],ciphertext[1],ciphertext[2],ciphertext[3]);
                        xprintf("**************************\n");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf ("false");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    printf ("false");
                }
            }

        }

    }// End While

}//end of C_Entry
```

So the problem is that It takes just the last line and repeat all the time the same encryption of that line:

```
    $**************************
ccddeeff 8899aabb 44556677   112233
Go encrypt..
Encrypt do
ne..
d6e4d64b 27d8d055 c5c7573a 8df4e9aa
**************************
******************
********
ccddeeff 8899aabb 44556677   112233
Go encrypt..
Encrypt done..
d6e4d64b 27d
8d055 c5c7573a 8df4e9aa
**************************
**************************
ccddeeff
 8899aabb 44556677   112233
Go encrypt..
Encrypt done..
d6e4d64b 27d8d055 c5c7573a 8df
4e9aa
**************************
**************************
ccddeeff 8899aabb 44556677
   112233
Go encrypt..
Encrypt done..
d6e4d64b 27d8d055 c5c7573a 8df4e9aa
**********
****************
**************************
ccddeeff 8899aabb 44556677   112233
Go enc
rypt..
Encrypt done..
d6e4d64b 27d8d055 c5c7573a 8df4e9aa
....................
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was spaces in python file: the for loop  must contains

```
       ser.write(clear_msg)
       time.sleep(0.4)
       print(ser.read(70))
```

By that way, it will not take just the last plaintext from the plaintext file.

```
import string
import serial
import time
from array import array
import struct
import binascii

ser = serial.Serial(
                    port='COM4',\
                    baudrate=230400,\
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
                    timeout=0)  

f = open(r'C:\\Users\\user\\Plaintxt.txt', 'r')
for a in f:
   plaintxt_16b=a[0:32]
   plaintext=binascii.unhexlify(plaintxt_16b)
   clear_msg=b'\x24'+b'\x73'+b'\x10'+plaintext
   ser.write(clear_msg)
   time.sleep(0.4)
   print(ser.read(70))
ser.close()                # close ports
```

My problem is resolved. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do as following:

```
f = open("your_file", "r")
for line in f:
    do_something(line)
f.close()
```

or as the comment pointed out:

```
with open("your_file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something(line)
```

Python will iterate over every line and give the string of the line as variable line here. You can handle every line in the file this way. Also, doing so, python reads one line each time, so it is effective for larger files.

Comment: I would personally use `with open("your_file", "r") as f: for line in f: do_something(line)`. Which avoids the possibility of not closing the file in case of exceptions.

Comment: @DaanTimmer I agree. I personally do not use "with" key word very often, but it is a better practice.

Comment: I am so sorry, It works just one time then I am back the encryption one line

Comment: 2nd code snipped should start `with open("your_file") as f:`

Comment: I already correct it, f = open(r'C:\\Users\\user\\Plaintxt.txt', 'r')   or as you notice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

During your for loop

```
for a in range (0,2):

   line_array=lines[a]
   plaintxt_16b=line_array[0:32]

   plaintext=binascii.unhexlify(plaintxt_16b)
   clear_msg=b'\x24'+b'\x73'+b'\x10'+plaintext
```

your overwrite the variable `clear_msg` in each iteration.
Once you leave the loop it contains the last value. In your case the last line (encrypted). Then you send the variable `clear_msg` several times without changing its content.
You need to indent the following block as well:

```
print(clear_msg)
ser.write(clear_msg)
time.sleep(0.4)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know ;-) Just thought it said readline ;-) and not readline_s_

Comment: @jonie83, do you mean that i must remove for example the print(clear_msg)??

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.dk/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html), calling readlines() makes your code slower, less explicit, less concise, for absolutely no benefit.

A good approach to open a file without the need of closing it is by using `while`

```
with open(file) as f:
    line = f.read().splitlines()
```

`line` is a list that contains all the lines of your file. You can iterate and get any entry as you would do in a list

Comment: It gives me errors with that splitlines, it is like it can't read any line

Comment: What kind of errors. The splitlines is there to assure that you don't get th `\n` character.

Comment: Sorry, it was a syntax error from me, but it still give me just one line.